# How to underline a portion of textview when using text watcher?

Tags: android, textwatcher, underline

I am using text watcher to change the text in text view with the edit text  value.
I just want to underline that text which is changed not the whole text view.

```
          tv1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



                txtview.setText(sen1.replace("___", " "+s.toString()));

                update1 = (String) txtview.getText();


            }
        });
```

I tried these

`SpannableString`,
`setPaintFlags()`; of `TextView`, makes my whole text view underline.
`Html.fromHtml()`;  it is for static strings

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sen1.replace("___", "<u>" + s.toString() + "</u>")));
```